# How to connect database in vb.net(Database is installed in mixed mode)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written the following code to connect database. I'm using visual studio 2010 and sql server R2( Mixed mode authentication). When i debug my code then an error is shown.
The error is "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
I think I have to put my userid and password of sql server in the time of create connection but I don't know the coding. So pls help me

'Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=SOFTSKOOL-PC1;initial catalog=Sonali_Test_July;Integrated Security=True")

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    'con.Close()
    Return con
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make sure that the Mixed Autentification is on 
[See the link](http://sarangasl.blogspot.fr/2011/06/sql-server-authentication-enabling.html)

Standard Security

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Trusted Connection

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Connection to a SQL Server instance
The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same for all SQL Server connection strings.

Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Trusted Connection from a CE device
A Windows CE device is most often not authenticated and logged in to a domain but it is possible to use SSPI or trusted connection and authentication from a CE device using this connection string.

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Note that this will only work on a CE device.

Connect via an IP address

Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
DBMSSOCN=TCP/IP is how to use TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes. At the end of the Data Source is the port to use. 1433 is the default port for SQL Server. Read more here.

Enable MARS

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;